# File compression/checking for data corruption in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

For large files or other files that are not necessarily text, how can i compress them and what are the most efficient methods to check for data corruption? any tutorials on these kinds of algorithms would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use CRC32 or any other hashing methods (SHA1, MD5) if it's just for checking data corruption. You can google for library on your own. For compression/checking corruption, I think you can find many types of compression library that is open-source online also (zip, gzip, etc.).

Comment: which one would be the most efficient one for large files lets say GB?

Comment: what do you mean by efficient? fast? creates less collisions? without a metric there is no such thing as best/most ____.

Comment: yes create less collisions and fast

Comment: Find a library (preferably a library with .zip as well as a few other common compression formats) and try it on your data set.  Comparing different compression formats against your actual data is the *only* way you're going to get an accurate answer.  IMHO..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compression, LZO should be helpful. Easy to use and library easily available.
For data corruption check, CRC ca
http://cppgm.blogspot.in/2008/10/calculation-of-crc.html

Answer (score 2):

For general compression, I would recommend Huffman coding. It's very easy to learn, a full-featured (2-pass) coder/decoder can be written in <4 hours if you understand it. It is part of DEFLATE which is part of the .zip format. Once you have that down, learn LZ77, then put them together and make your own DEFLATE implementation.

Alternatively, use zlib, the library everyone uses for zip files.

For large files, I wouldn't recommend CRC32 like everyone is telling you. Larger files suffer from birthday corruption pretty easily. What I mean is that as a file gets larger, a 32-bit checksum can only find an increasingly limited number of errors. A fast implementation of a hash - say, MD5 - would do you well. Yes MD5 is cryptographically broken but I'm assuming, considering your question, that you're not working on a security-conscious problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hamming codes are a possibility. The idea is to insert a few sum-bits at each N bits of data , and initialize each of them with 0 or 1, such that the sum of some of the bits of data and sum-bits is 1 all the time. In case in which a sum is not 1, looking at the values of these sum-bits, you can see what bits of data were lost.

There are lots of other possibilities, as the previous post says.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code#General_algorithm